# label disappear when use size to fit?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am displaying a label on UI in iOS using code, not from storyboard. When the size of the label is large then it does display accurate it go outside the view so I decided to use `sizeToFit` in iOS. But when I apply this thing on label then it does appear on view. Please tell why my label does not appear in this case.

Here is the code for the label:

```
 self.label_company = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 30, 150, 100)];
[self.label_company setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];
```

Comment: when are you calling sizetofit?

Comment: after the code i wrote

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 30, 150, 100)];
[label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12]];
label1.text=@"yourdata";
[self.view addSubview:label1];
[label1 sizeToFit];
```

Make sure you have some text in your label as well as add it to your view.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have no text set to the label hence calling `sizeToFit` is making its width 0 as there is no size of the label in terms of width.
Set `self.label_company.text = @"Some text"` and then call `sizeToFit`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you set the text of the label before calling size to fit.